# Limitations for JRules decision table

Tags: ilog, jrules

What is the maximum number of rows that are permitted while designing a decision table? Is there any difference with execution speed if a single decision table is split in to multiple ones with same pre conditions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on maximum number rows in decision tables. And yes number of rows in decision table impact the performance. It takes too much time even for compilation of decision table with more rows. While execution it will run through all the entries in Decision table. So it is usually recommended not to use more than 200 rows. Splitting of decision table is better idea. But rather than simple splitting if we can use some filters (say State in a,b,c in Decision Table 1 / State e,f,g in Decision Table 2)in precondition to narrow down our search criteria.